# Reinstall Preinstalled Windows 7 on a Toshiba Laptop

Tags: windows-7, reinstall, toshiba-laptop

I'm having problems with a Toshiba Satellite L745 which came preinstalled  with Windows 7 (According to the product key label on the bottom Home Premium QA).

Basically it is freezing whenever updates run and sometimes when they don't. System recovery doesn't seem to be helping and I'm hoping to go nuclear and just reinstall windows.

But there's no disk because windows came preinstalled. I've also read online that a lot of times preinstalled windows will have a recovery partition that you can access by holding down Alt+F10 but this doesn't seem to be working.  What is my next step?

Comment: Check if there is even a recovery partition on the HDD.  Use Administrative Tools / Computer Management / Storage / Disk Management to view the partitions on the hard drive.

Comment: @sawdust I found another partition via F12 while booting. It had a repair windows option and no others. Selecting that ground away for a while and...then nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are instructions (found [here](https://www.csd.toshiba.com/cgi-bin/tais/support/jsp/bulletinDetail.jsp?soid=2737864&pf=true)) for going back to factory fresh software instance for Toshiba laptops:

*To restore the original factory software image on your computer follow these steps:*

- Make sure the computer is turned off ("Shut-down" from the Windows Start menu)
- Remove any peripherals such an external mouse, keyboard, monitor, USB flash drive etc.
- Make sure the AC Adapter is plugged in and working.
- Press and hold down the 0 (zero) key on the keyboard while powering on the computer.
- Release it when the recovery warning screen appears.
- If the recovery process offers a choice of Operating Systems, select the appropriate one for you.
- A warning screen appears, stating that when the recovery is executed all data will be deleted and rewritten.
- Click Yes to continue.
- When the Toshiba Recovery Wizard opens select "Recovery of Factory Software" or the appropriate option for your needs.
- Continue to follow the directions restarting as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

> But there's no disk because windows came preinstalled.

You are expected to make your own recovery discs with the supplied "Toshiba Recovery Media Creator" utility.

> I've also read online that a lot of times preinstalled windows will have a recovery partition that you can access by holding down Alt+F10 but this doesn't seem to be working.

The *Toshiba User's Guide* says:

> While powering on your computer, press the ***F12*** key when the initial
>   TOSHIBA screen displays.
>
> The boot menu appears.
>
> Using the arrow keys to scroll down, select the HDD Recovery
>   option, and then press the ENTER key.
>
> A warning screen should appear.

If you type "yes", then you should get to the *Toshiba Recovery Wizard* screen.

Answer (score 0):

Can you keep pressing F8 while the laptop is booting. Sometimes Toshiba modifies the boot options screen to add a "repair" option or similar, which then boots from the recovery partition.

Answer (score 0):

just after the computer is turned on start tapping the f8 key. After the toshiba splash screen goes away you will get the window asking if you want to repair windows. select that and there will be options for toshiba recovery or whatnot, if it is available.