# Reinstalling Windows 7 on a Toshiba Satellite L750

Tags: windows-7, toshiba-laptop

My Toshiba L750 laptop came with Windows preinstalled and I would like to reinstall it as it is becoming a bit cluttered and slow. I attempted to follow the steps detailed in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/398998/reinstall-preinstalled-windows-7-on-a-toshiba-laptop) by using the Recovery Media Creator to burn a set of DVDs, but it did not work. The disks could not boot, and when I put them back in the computer, I got a popup saying that a blank disk had been inserted.
Pressing 0 while booting my computer does not do anything.
I installed Arch Linux on my computer, but I don't think I messed up the recovery partitions when I was installing it. I am able to boot into the Windows Recovery Environment, but it does not give me an option to do a reset.
My brother has the same laptop - if I make recovery disks on his computer will they work in my computer? If not, is there any way to reinstall windows without buying recovery disks from Toshiba?

Comment: Try making the recovery partition the active partition (so the BIOS tries to boot from it first). Generally the disks are just a copy of what is on the recovery partition and are used to recover if the drive needed to be replaced. This is not the same as the Windows Recovery Environment - it includes options to restore the system to factory defaults which is Windows + various OEM software and customizations.

Answer (score 0):

If the laptops are identical then, yes, you should be able to recover using media created from your brother's laptop.

The Windows key is an OEM key and is re-used a vast number of times and is built-in with the recovery image.

This is THE most important reason why it is crucial to always make the recovery disks when you first buy the laptop.